# How to determine which columns are foreign keys in sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want to write a custom base class (using declarative) with a method, that returns all column names which are not primary or foreign keys. This would be used to filter pandas.DataFrame. It looks like this now:

```
Base = declarative_base()

class CustomBase(Base):
  __abstract__ = True

  @classmethod
  def get_filter(cls):
    return [column.name for column in cls.__table__.columns]
```

Now suppose that I have a new class (and suppose that I have the other classes which I have a relationship to):

```
class Model(CustomBase):
  id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
  date = Column(Date)
  data_1 = Column(Integer)
  data_2 = Column(Integer)
  account = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('account.id'))
```

What I have is this:

```
>>> Model.get_filter()
['id','date','data_1','data_2','account']
```

but I want this:

```
>>> Model.get_filter()
['date','data_1','data_2']
```

I checked the [Mapper](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.mapper.Mapper) documentation, which I can get with `inspect(Model)`, and there is a collection for primary keys, but I have not found something similar for foreign keys. Can you suggest something?

**EDIT:**
The solution was

```
@classmethod
def get_filter(cls):
  return [column.name for column in cls.__table__.columns if not column.primary_key and not column.foreign_key]
```

Please note that `column.foreign_key` is a set, which is empty if the column is not a foreign key.

Comment: The `foreign_keys` attribute is not listed in the [Column](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column) documentation, so I think that answer is outdated already.

Comment: Check [`ColumnElement.foreign_keys`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.ColumnElement.foreign_keys), though it is rather poorly documented. A `Column` is a `ColumnElement`, so the dupe target does apply, at least to some extent.

Comment: Thanks, that is good to know for future reference :)